# What are Python3 libraries which replace "from scikits.audiolab import Format, Sndfile"

Tags: python-3.x, speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services, scikits

Hope you'll are doing good. I am new to python. I am trying to use audio.scikits library in python3 verion. I have a working code version in 2.7(with audio.scikits) . While I am running with python3 version I am getting the **Import Error: No Module Named 'Version'** error. I get to know that python3 is not anymore supporting audio.scikits(If I am not wrong). Can anyone suggest me replacing library for audio.scikits where I can use all the functionalities like audio.scikits do OR any other solution which might helps me. Thanks in advance.

2.7 Version Code :

```
from scikits.audiolab import Format, Sndfile
from scipy.signal import firwin, lfilter

array = np.array(all)
fmt = Format('flac', 'pcm16')
nchannels = 1
cd, FileNameTmp = mkstemp('TmpSpeechFile.wav')
# making the file .flac
afile =  Sndfile(FileNameTmp, 'w', fmt, nchannels, RawRate) 
#writing in the file
afile.write_frames(array)
SendSpeech(FileNameTmp)
```

To check entire code please visit :[Google Asterisk Reference Code(modifying based on this code)](http://%20https://github.com/ederwander/Asterisk-Google-Speech-Recognition/blob/master/pahh.py)

I want to modify this code with python3 supported libraries. Here I am doing this for Asterisk-Microsoft-Speech To Text SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly the link code you paste is `Asterisk-Google-Speech-Recognition`, it's not the `Microsoft-Speech-To-Text`, if you want get a sample about `Microsoft-Speech-To-Text` you could refer to the official doc[:Recognize speech from an audio file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/quickstarts/speech-to-text-from-file?tabs=linux&pivots=programming-language-python).

And about your problem you said, yes it's not completely compatible, in the github issue there is a solution for it, you could refer to this [comment](https://github.com/buriburisuri/speech-to-text-wavenet/issues/106#issuecomment-455104920).